# Criação de diretórios em Python

Tags: python, diretório

Eu tenho uma lista de diretórios a serem criados que tem essa estrutura :

```
Bla / Bla / Bla1.md

Bla / Bla / Bla2.md

Blu / Blue.md

Ble.md
```

Porém os arquivos `.md` não devem ser criados, mas as pastas que contém os mesmo devem, e para tal eu fiz o seguinte script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os


def build ( address ) :

    address = '/home/bezerk/Imagens/' + address

    if not os.path.exists ( address ) :

        os.makedirs ( address )


with open ( 'Arquivo.txt', 'r' ) as file :

    for line in file.readlines () :

        if line.endswith ( '.md' ) :

            # Tratamento aqui

            build ( line [:-3] )

        else :

            build ( line )
```

Porém não sei o motivo de o python não reconhecer isso `Bla / Bla / Bla1.md` mas um item separado como esse aqui `Ble.md` ele reconhece, se alguém puder me dar insights para resolver eu fico grato

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "o python não reconhece"? fiz um teste aqui granvando os diretorios com os nomes que vc sugere e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Quando eu rodo aqui no meu pc ele não cria as pastas como `Bla / Bla / Bla1.md` que tem mais de um diretório dentro, mas se eu colocar no arquivo `txt` apenas pastas sem subpastas ele as cria perfeitamente ( É isso que eu estava estranhando pois não via nada errado no código, mas ... ) - e quando ele cria, as pastas são criadas com extensão `.md` e vira uma bagunça

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer os testes abaixo e se vc obtiver os mesmos resultados, o erro esta na sua lógica de tratamento do arquivo, se os resultados forem diferentes há algo de podre no reino do SO :-) vá na linha de comando:

```
$ cd ~
~$ python

from os import makedirs as mkdir
d1 = 'teste1/bla/bla/bla.md'
mkdir(d1)
```

Saia do pyton e execute o comando `tree` para ver a arvore criada a partir de teste1.

```
tree teste1
```

[image: Arvore criada pel makedirs]

Volte ao python e faça:

```
d2 = 'test2 / bla /bla /bla.md'
mkdir(d2)
```

Saia do python e tente rodar o comando `tree` para obter a árvore do diretório teste2 e vc obterá um erro:

```
$ tree teste2
teste2 [error opening dir]
```

Por que isso acontece? pelo motivo de que, na verdade, não existe um diretorio chamado "teste2" e sim "teste2 " (com um espaço depois do 2), então comando `tree` deve ser executado da seguinte maneira:

```
$ tree teste2\
```

Note que após a barra há um espaço, este comando resulta na figura abaixo:

[image: Arvore gerada pelo makedirs com "teste2 "]

Executei os testes em um ubuntu 16, talvez o seu problema esteja no espaços entre as barras, a não ser que isso seja mandatório, tente retira-los, espaços em nomes de diretorios pode ser fonte de problemas, se tiver que mante-los lembre-se que vc tera que usar scape para referencia-los.